# Google Bookmarks and Chrome Bookmark Sync -- Different?

Tags: google-bookmarks

There appears to be two distinct sets of bookmarks maintained by Google.  If you visit [Google Notebook](https://www.google.com/notebook) or [Google Bookmarks](https://www.google.com/bookmarks) you get one set.  And if you sync Chrome accounts you get another.  My question is:  how can I get one set of bookmarks maintained on Google's web apps and through Chrome?  I want to be able to access the bookmarks I have synced with Chrome from a web app when I'm using a public computer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Chrome Bookmark Sync is stored in Google Docs, under My Folders. Look there.

Comment: Never would have thought to look there, I don't use Docs on my own account, only my school's Google Account.  Seems strange that they maintain two copies...

Comment: I know. I had the same mental boggle when I found it out. On the good side, you can easily export from the Google Bookmarks page and import into Chrome Bookmarks Manager.

Comment: alas, no longer. :(

Comment: There's still the two sets (and my Google Bookmarks are still out there, gathering digital dust like my Delicious ones) but no, they're not under Google Docs anymore. But things like the Chromemarks can still get to them, so there must be available somehow.